# plotly multiple axes that change dynamically with plot

Tags: python, plotly

So consider the following plot with multiple y-axes (taken from here [link](https://plotly.com/python/multiple-axes/))

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

# Create figure with secondary y-axis
fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])

# Add traces
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=[1, 2, 3], y=[40, 50, 60], name="yaxis data"),
    secondary_y=False,
)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=[2, 3, 4], y=[4, 5, 6], name="yaxis2 data"),
    secondary_y=True,
)

# Add figure title
fig.update_layout(
    title_text="Double Y Axis Example"
)

# Set x-axis title
fig.update_xaxes(title_text="xaxis title")

# Set y-axes titles
fig.update_yaxes(title_text="<b>primary</b> yaxis title", secondary_y=False)
fig.update_yaxes(title_text="<b>secondary</b> yaxis title", secondary_y=True)

fig.show()
```

Is there anyway to get the axes to 'hide' and 'un-hide' as we click and unclick 'yaxis data' and 'yaxis2 data'? I need to construct a plot with more than 2 y-axes, and I would like the axes to 'hide' and 'unhide' as the user clicks the respective curve. Thanks for any help/guidance.

Comment: are you open to using **dash**? it's straight forward where callbacks can be used

Comment: Hi Rob.. Yes, I'd be open to using dash. How do I apply the app you created below with the fig creation above? Thanks for your help

Comment: I've updated answer to include figure creation as well.   didn't answer this way because figure creation code obscures the core of the answer and is just a copy paste of your code

Comment: ah ok.. I tried running it this way as well, but I get an 
AttributeError: 'DummyMod' object has no attribute 'startswith'                                                   Problem seems to be with app = JupyterDash(__name__)

Comment: update: issue is with databricks.. got it to run in vs code no problem.. thanks Rob!

Comment: Rob could I ask you one more question: is this possible to do with a third trace, or n many traces?. From what I can see, it only allows two y-axes. Thanks again!

Comment: further updated answer.  you will see I have not changed **dash** callback,  just generated a figure that has more traces and y-axes

Answer (score 4):

- using this technique https://community.plotly.com/t/dash-callback-on-legend-item-clicked/36672/3
- the following **dash** app makes y-axes visible/invisible on legend click events
- have generated a figure that creates as many y-axes as traces.  This demonstrates that this isn't a limited solution

```
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import numpy as np

# build a figure with defined number of traces, each trace using it's own yaxis
TRACES = 9
fig = go.Figure(
    [
        go.Scatter(
            x=np.linspace(0, 10, 10),
            y=np.random.uniform(1 * 10 ** y, 5 * 10 ** y, 10),
            name=str(y),
            yaxis=f"y{'' if y==0 else y+1}",
        )
        for y in range(TRACES)
    ]
).update_layout(
    {
        f"yaxis{'' if ax==0 else ax+1}": {
            "position": 1 - (ax / 20),
            "overlaying":None if ax==0 else "y",
        }
        for ax in range(TRACES)
    }
)
# some space for all the y-axes
fig = fig.update_layout(xaxis={"domain": [0, 0.4]})

# Build App
app = JupyterDash(__name__)
app.layout = dash.html.Div(
    [
        dash.dcc.Graph(id="fig", figure=fig),
    ],
)

@app.callback(
    Output("fig", "figure"), Input("fig", "restyleData"), State("fig", "figure")
)
def graphClick(clickData, fig):
    if not clickData:
        raise dash.exceptions.PreventUpdate
    yax = {
        f"yaxis{'' if tn==0 else tn+1}": {
            "visible": clickData[0]["visible"][i] != "legendonly"
        }
        for i, tn in enumerate(clickData[1])
    }
    return go.Figure(fig).update_layout(**yax)


# Run app and display result inline in the notebook
app.run_server(mode="inline")
```